# View local storage for React Native app when developing?

Tags: react-native

Is there a good way to view all the key/value pairs in local storage while developing? I want to debug a problem. Yes I could set a breakpoint with the debugger keyword, but there's got to be a viewer command or menu item right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, there's no way to do this within the browser's dev tools. I wish there were. But, I can think of two ways of solving your problem. Hope this helps.

1. Use [getAllKeys](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/asyncstorage.html#getallkeys) and then map through them, outputting their key/value along the way. This is probably the easiest, most straight forward.
2. Use native debug techniques such as using [Web Inspector](https://developer.apple.com/library/iad/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/SafariJSDatabaseGuide/Name-ValueStorage/Name-ValueStorage.html) to view the local key/value store on iOS devices. (which is probably not the right tool in your case as it appears to be related to browser based local storage from what I can tell)

I'm not an iOS developer, so I'm unable to give you detailed direction here. I'd recommend adding the ios and android tags to your question to attract attention from those communities.

Answer (score 2):

There is a way to view the local storage.

**Note: i'm assuming you're working with Xcode and iOS.**

`AsyncStorage` actually saves the key-value store to a simple json file called `manifest.json`. In iOS it saves it into the Documents folder in a dedicated sub-folder named `RCTAsyncLocalStorage_V1`.

If you're developing on the simulator you can locate the file like so:

1. Go to the this folder: `~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices`.
2. Look for a folder named `RCTAsyncLocalStorage_V1`.
3. In this folder you'll find the manifest file (`manifest.json`) - this is your storage file.

If you have several apps which use AsyncStorage (and therefore multiple folder/manifest files), it will be kinda hard to tell which is which. It is possible to find the exact documents folder of your current app via debugging or console printing on the native side, but that would be a little off-topic.

Comment: @Aartal This is very interesting. Following your advice, I found about 50+ devices in the `~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices` directory. Each device looks something like `1ADF9116-4CF9-4554-B22D-AF298A2B29C7`. After some trial and error, I drilled into the device folder to find the `RCTAsyncLocalStorage_V1` folder you mentioned (but not every device had one) so that the entire path was `~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/1ADF9116-4CF9-4554-B22D-AF298A2B29C7/data/Containers/Data/Application/8F2B73D2-7687-4323-81FC-A06BBB97D28D/Documents/RCTAsyncLocalStorage_V1/manifest.json`

Comment: In that folder, along side the manifest.json, I also found other files containing the value of any saved key/value pair. This is insightful, so thank you for the info. However, I would love to understand how to isolate which DEVICE one is using. With 50+, it's a bit arduous otherwise.

Comment: @ChrisGeirman the device list you see is actually a list of apps, with a randomly generated ID, so in the apps where you used AsyncStorage you'll have the json file. For this reason I mentioned that it will be hard to know which is your app, and that you can print this info to the console from the native side.

Comment: Gotcha, but you didn't mention how

Comment: You can log the path to the documents folder anywhere in the AppDelegate.m file like so: `NSLog(@"%@",[[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject]);`

Comment: They sure do bury it. BTW, I was able to quickly find which device and directory by just creating an async key in my code named 'FOOBAR' (or anything unique really), then doing a grep for it from the Devices folder `grep -r FOOBAR .`